# Why does table headers and data overlap in Ant table if some columns are fixed in some browsers?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, firefox, antd, tablelayout

Using the **Ant table design** to build a table structure with many columns.
The first 3 columns are fixed here. For these fixed columns, the table headers and data are correctly displayed. 
But for the balance columns the headers and data overlap even when scrolling. This happens both in **chrome and safari**, but not in **Firefox**. Firefox seems to be working properly.

My current css code,

```
   .ant-table th {
      line-height: 1;
      text-align: right;
      padding: 15px 9px;
      overflow-wrap: normal;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

Comment: Please share some minimal reproducible example. One cannot discern the problem from description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

table-layout:fixed is correctly handled by firefox. But not by other browsers chrome and safari. Changing table-layout:auto will handle the issue.

```
.ant-table-layout-fixed table {
    table-layout: auto;
}
```

Comment: This corrects the overlapping issue. 
But in IOS (In all browsers), Scroll bar is appearing inside the non-fixed part of the table which causes reducing the height of last row.
For Linux it looks fine.

Comment: I have this same issues in my project and I also have tried your suggestions but it's not solving my issue. Can you help me provide another way to solve this problems? Thank you.